SAPUI5 Application cache buster not working
I am really struggling with the set up of application cache buster for our SAPUI5 application.
It is running as a standalone application on an ABAP system. However, every time we change the UI, we have to delete the browser cache to see the changes. This is why I decided to set up the application cache buster, but it doesn't seem to work at all for us.
My index.html looks like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Name</title>
        <script
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            src="/sap/public/bc/ui5_ui5/resources/sap-ui-cachebuster/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
            data-sap-ui-app-cache-buster="./"
            data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
                "<app_path>": "./"
            }'
            data-sap-ui-oninit="module:sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-async="true"
            data-sap-ui-frameOptions="trusted"
        ></script>
    </head>
    <body class="sapUiBody">
        <div
            data-sap-ui-component
            data-name="<app_path>"
            data-id="container"
            data-settings='{"id" : "AppName"}'
        ></div>
    </body>
</html>


My package.json file looks like this:
{
    "name": "appname",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Description",
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "ts-typecheck": "tsc --noEmit",
        "start": "ui5 serve -o index.html",
        "start-cdn": "ui5 serve  -o index-cdn.html --config ui5-dist.yaml",
        "start-flp": "fiori run --open \"test/flpSandbox.html?sap-ui-xx-viewCache=false#AppName-display\"",
        "start-noflp": "fiori run --open \"index.html?sap-client=075&sap-ui-xx-viewCache=false\"",
        "lint": "eslint webapp ",
        "build-dev": "ui5 build dev --clean-dest --include-task=generateCachebusterInfo",
        "build": "ui5 build --clean-dest --include-task=generateCachebusterInfo",
        "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.(ts|js|json|yml|yaml|xml)\"",
        "ncu": "ncu",
        "ncu-upgrade": "ncu -u",
        "deploy": "npm run build-dev && ui5-deployer deploy --config ./ui5-deploy.yaml"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "7.21.5",
        "@babel/core": "7.21.8",
        "@babel/preset-env": "7.21.5",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.21.5",
        "@odata2ts/odata2ts": "^0.31.0",
        "@sap-ux/ui5-middleware-fe-mockserver": "2",
        "@sap/ux-ui5-tooling": "1.10.4",
        "@sapui5/types": "1.120.0",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.5.16",
        "@types/openui5": "^1.113.0",
        "@types/qunit": "2.19.5",
        "@types/sinon": "10.0.14",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.59.2",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.59.2",
        "@ui5/cli": "^3.11.3",
        "eslint": "8.39.0",
        "eslint-plugin-ui5": "0.1.0",
        "npm-check-updates": "16.10.9",
        "typescript": "5.0.4",
        "ui5-deployer": "1.1.1",
        "ui5-middleware-livereload": "0.8.2",
        "ui5-middleware-simpleproxy": "0.9.7",
        "ui5-tooling-transpile": "0.7.8"
    },
    "ui5": {
        "dependencies": [
            "@sap/ux-ui5-tooling",
            "ui5-tooling-transpile",
            "@sap-ux/ui5-middleware-fe-mockserver",
            "ui5-middleware-simpleproxy",
            "ui5-middleware-livereload"
        ]
    }
}


After the build, the sap-ui-cachebuster-info.json is generated and looks like this:
enter image description here
Every time, I deploy a change, I execute this report: /ui5/app_index_calculate
and yet the change does not appear until I manually delete the browser cache.
Can you please advice what I could be doing wrong?
